# Load Balancer with broadcasting websocket

Tags: websocket, .net-core, signalr, load-balancing

Although we have many questions about LoadBalancing websockets I couldn't find one addressing my specific scenario.

I will have the following design:

```
                           |=============|
        -------------------|  ActiveMQ   |--------------------
        |                  |=============|                   |
        |                                                    |
|=============|            |=============|            |=============|
|  MyApp_01   |------------|   Database  |------------|  MyApp_02   |
|=============|            |=============|            |=============|
                                                             |
                                  ---------------------------
                                  |
                           |=============|
                           |LoadBalancer |
                           |=============|
                                  |
                                  |
                           |=============|
                           |   Client    |
                           |=============|
```

I have the following components:

- My application deployed in two instances
- An `ActiveMQ` queue which both my application listens to
- A database which both applications write the queue messages.
- A Load Balancer, yet to be defined between Nginx or some Microsoft Service Fabric (I really don't know much about these technologies, what makes this even harder to search about :S)
- My client app that connects to a load balancer

Both instances of my app are listening on the same queue. Upon receiving a message, an instance removes it from the queue, saves it on database and broadcast it through websockets to any client connected to it. Both instances are listening to the queue so any of them can be the one to remove the message from the queue, I don't have any control over it (nor should I, I think) .
The problem comes when, on the above scenario for example, we have a client connected to `MyApp_02` and `MyApp_01` is the one who gets and broadcasts the message. The client will never receive any message because it is connected to `MyApp_02`.

What can I do on this scenario? Should I find a way of broadcasting from all instances...? How would I do that? Is there anything on Nginx or Microsoft Service Fabric that would help me?

If it matters, I'm using `.Net Core 2.2` with `SignalR` in my application.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: one clarification required to answer the question - do you have control on how the messages are coming to message queue ? because how you can handle the situation will mainly depend on if you can control the way the messages are published to the Queue.

Comment: What do you mean? I do not this kind of control. This queue is used to integrate data between my system and a 3rd one. We have agreed on a message format and the other system simply put messages in this format on the queue.

Comment: Writing it again (missed my edit window): I think `Topics` can help you solve the issue. Both Apps can subscribe to a `MessageDeleted` topic, and upon receiving from this topic, normally talk to the connected client. This case.. both would receive the deleted messages.. that maybe be ok or not to you, depends on the requirements. One thing that it's not clear: Where do you have SignalR running? Shouldn't you have a central app for this, instead of having it on your `MyApp_xx` That way the app's responsibility is just processing messages.. not dealing with clients.

Comment: Hi jpgrassi, thanks for the answer. We have considered a solution including another messaging service broadcasting to all the "MyApp_XX" instances as you suggested. I think it also would work, but my client wants to be sure we do not have another option. Including another messaging service is expensive for him and would create another point of failure in the application (what if the queue is down? Or a message is not delivered? .......?). They want to be sure there isn't a solution "out of the box" to deal with load balancing in these scenarios... any ideas?

Comment: About the SignalR, we have them running on both MyApp instances. Thats one of the purposes of load balancing, actually. That way we can balance the connections on both apps and don't overload one of them

Comment: You already have this problem with a queue being down, or message not delivered, that's just the nature of dealing with message queues. Your architecture has to take care of that. Your problem is clear: Your `MyApp_xx` cannot be the ones connected directly with clients, as yourself stated. There's a load balancer behind it, so it more or less defeats the "stateless" purpose of it. Have you considered SignalR Service on Azure?

Comment: Imagine this solution: You have a central, SignalR Service, where all your clients are connected. Your `MyApp_xxx` deals with processing messages from the queue. When they are deleted, the apps send tell SignalR Service: Hey, message deleted. Then it forwards to connected clients. Now, any app can delete any message without being tied to any client. You can put 100 instances of it, without having any concerns.

Comment: @jpgrassi thing is having another messaging service is another server to fail. It wouldn't be the same one. I get your idea of having one micro-service to only deal with the websockets but it isn't much different than having both apps dealing with it. In both scenarios I need a new messaging service and communication among my nodes. And in your scenario I don't have any balance on the socket connections...

Comment: Depends. If you go the route of using Azure SignalR service, you definitely can scale it. In fact, it's even better than your design now because if you have too many connections, you have to spawn a whole new app instance, configure it on the LB, whereas in using a product/service out of the box is easier. Also, I'm pretty sure Azure offers some pretty good up-time on its services so.. if you keep thinking always on "But what if fails" then you're pretty much stuck :). But honestely I don't see another way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192455/discussion-between-jpgrassi-and-joao-menighin).

Comment: Its not me, its my client n_n'. Also I forgot to address the azure part. We wont use it. The application is a critical one. We will have on premise servers... So... yeah...